# How do I email the results of a php form?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have made a quiz in php and am trying to email the results that are seen after clicking the submit button. I know I need to use the email function but I'm not sure how to get the entire page into the body of the email.

Here is the html

```
   <form action= "Graded.php"  method="post" id="quiz">

<div class="required">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" required>

</div>

<style>
    .required:after { content:" required*"; }
</style>
<br>

<div class="required">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" required>

</div>

<style>
    .required:after { content:" required*"; }
</style>
<br>
<br>



<li>
Question 1: The Chinese zodiac associates a sign with each month.
<div>
<input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-A" value="A" required />
<label for="question-1-answers-A">True </label>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-B" value="B" required />
<label for="question-1-answers-B">False </label>
<div>
</li>

<li>
Question 2: Chinese zodiac signs represent different types of personalities.
<div>
<input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-A" value="A" required/>
<label for="question-2-answers-A">True </label>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-B" value="B" required/>
<label for="question-2-answers-B">False </label>
<div>
</li>

<li>
Question 3: The Chinese zodiac signs each have an equivalent constellations, like those of the occidental zodiac.
<div>
<input type="radio" name="question-3-answers" id="question-3-answers-A" value="A" required />
<label for="question-3-answers-A">True </label>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="question-3-answers" id="question-3-answers-B" value="B" required />
<label for="question-3-answers-B">False </label>
<div>
</li>

<li>

Question 4: Which sign is not part of the Chinese zodiac?

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-4-answers" id="question-4-answers-A" value="A" required />
        <label for="question-4-answers-A">A) Rat </label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-4-answers" id="question-4-answers-B" value="B" required/>
        <label for="question-4-answers-B">B) Fox </label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-4-answers" id="question-4-answers-C" value="C" required />
        <label for="question-4-answers-C">C) Pig</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-4-answers" id="question-4-answers-D" value="D" required/>
        <label for="question-4-answers-D">D) Tiger</label>
    </div>

</li>

<li>
Question 5: The Chinese zodiac traditionally begins with which sign?

 <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-5-answers-A" value="A" required />
        <label for="question-5-answers-A">A) Rat </label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-5-answers-B" value="B" required />
        <label for="question-5-answers-B">B) Fox </label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-5-answers-C" value="C" required />
        <label for="question-5-answers-C">C) Pig</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-5-answers-D" value="D" required />
        <label for="question-5-answers-D">D) Tiger</label>
    </div>
</li>

<li>
Question 6: The Chinese zodiac traditionally ends with which sign?

<div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-6-answers" id="question-6-answers-A" value="A" required />
        <label for="question-6-answers-A">A) Rat </label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-6-answers" id="question-6-answers-B" value="B" required />
        <label for="question-6-answers-B">B) Fox </label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-6-answers" id="question-6-answers-C" value="C" required />
        <label for="question-6-answers-C">C) Pig</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question-6-answers" id="question-6-answers-D" value="D" required />
        <label for="question-6-answers-D">D) Tiger</label>
</li>        
    </div>
<li>
Question 7: How many signs are in the Chinese zodiac? <input type="text" name="question-7-answers" value="" required>
<div>
Question 8: Which is the only reptile that is a sign in the Chinese zodiac? <input type="text" name="question-8-answers" value="" required>
<div>
Question 9: Which is the only imaginary animal that is a sign in the Chinese zodiac? <input type="text" name="question-9-answers" value="" required>
<div>
Question 10: Which is the only bird that is a sign in the Chinese zodiac? <input type="text" name="question-10-answers" value="" required>
<div>
</li>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset Quiz" class = "reset_button" />
</form>
```

and the php

```
<?php





$answer1 = $_POST['question-1-answers'];
$answer2 = $_POST['question-2-answers'];
$answer3 = $_POST['question-3-answers'];
$answer4 = $_POST['question-4-answers'];
$answer5 = $_POST['question-5-answers'];
$answer6 = $_POST['question-6-answers'];
$answer7 = $_POST['question-7-answers'];
$answer8 = $_POST['question-8-answers'];
$answer9 = $_POST['question-9-answers'];
$answer10 = $_POST['question-10-answers'];
$answer7 = strtolower(trim($answer7));
$answer8 = strtolower(trim($answer8));
$answer9 = strtolower(trim($answer9));
$answer10 = strtolower(trim($answer10));
$totalCorrect = 0;

if ($answer1 == "B") { $totalCorrect++; echo "Question 1 was Correct: The Chinese zodiac associates a sign with each month. Answer: False <br />\n"; }
else echo "Question 2 was incorrect. This is the correct answer:  The Chinese zodiac associates a sign with each month.  Answer: False <br />\n"; 

if ($answer2 == "A") { $totalCorrect++; echo "Question 2 was Correct:  Chinese zodiac signs represent different types of personalities. Answer: Ture <br />\n"; }
else echo "Question 2 was incorrect. This is the correct answer: Chinese zodiac signs represent different types of personalities.  Answer: True <br />\n";

if ($answer3 == "B") { $totalCorrect++; echo "Question 3 was Correct: The Chinese zodiac signs each have an equivalent constellations, like those of the occidental zodiac. Answer: False <br />\n";}
else echo"Question 3 was incorrect. This is the correct answer: Question 3: The Chinese zodiac signs each have an equivalent constellations, like those of the occidental zodiac.  Answer: False <br />\n";

if ($answer4 == "B") { $totalCorrect++; echo "Question 4 was Correct: Which sign is not part of the Chinese zodiac? Answer: Fox <br />\n";}
else echo "Question 4 was incorrect. This is the correct answer: Which sign is not part of the Chinese zodiac?   Answer: Fox <br />\n";

if ($answer5 == "A") { $totalCorrect++; echo "Question 5 was Correct:  The Chinese zodiac traditionally begins with which sign? Answer: Rat<br />\n";}
else echo"Question 5 was incorrect. This is the correct answer: The Chinese zodiac traditionally begins with which sign?   Answer: Rat <br />\n";

if ($answer6 == "C") { $totalCorrect++; echo "Question 6 was Correct: The Chinese zodiac traditionally ends with which sign? Answer: Pig <br />\n";}
else echo"Question 6 was incorrect. This is the correct answer: The Chinese zodiac traditionally ends with which sign?    Answer: Pig <br />\n";

if ($answer7 == "12" ||  $answer7 == "twelve") { $totalCorrect++; echo "Question 7 was Correct: How many signs are in the Chinese zodiac? Answer: 12 <br />\n";}
else echo"Question 7 was incorrect. This is the correct answer: How many signs are in the Chinese zodiac?    Answer: 12 <br />\n";

if ($answer8 == "Snake" || $answer8 == "snake") { $totalCorrect++; echo "Question 8 was Correct: Which is the only reptile that is a sign in the Chinese zodiac? Answer: Snake <br />\n";}
else echo "Question 8 was incorrect. This is the correct answer: Which is the only reptile that is a sign in the Chinese zodiac? Answer: Snake <br />\n";

if ($answer9 == "Dragon" || $answer9 == "dragon") { $totalCorrect++; echo "Question 9 was Correct: Which is the only imaginary animal that is a sign in the Chinese zodiac? Answer: Dragon <br />\n";}
else echo "Question 9 was incorrect. This is the correct answer: Which is the only imaginary animal that is a sign in the Chinese zodiac?   Answer: Dragon <br />\n";

if ($answer10 == "Rooster" ||  $answer10 == "rooster") { $totalCorrect++; echo "Question 10 was Correct: Which is the only bird that is a sign in the Chinese zodiac? Answer: Rooster <br />\n";}
else echo "Question 10 was incorrect. This is the correct answer: Which is the only bird that is a sign in the Chinese zodiac?    Answer: Rooster <br />\n";

echo "<div id='results'>$totalCorrect / 10 correct</div>";
$percent = $totalCorrect;
echo "You got a ", "$percent", "0%";
?>
```

Comment: Instead of echoing you should generate a string variable, and then echo it on the page and use it as the body text when calling the `mail` function

Answer (score -2):

I strongly recommend **validating** input post data before **Submitting, Posting, Storing, or Sending.**

But for the sake of completing the requested task, check out this registration function which should provide clarity:

```
   public function register($username, $password, $email, $firstName, $lastName)
{
    $time = time();
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // getting the users IP address
    $email_code = $email_code = uniqid( 'code_', true ); // Creating a unique string.
    $crypt = Bcrypt::genHash( $password );  // un-hast the password

    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`user_username`, `user_password`, `user_email`, `user_ip`, `user_creation_date`, `user_email_code`, `user_first_name`, `user_last_name`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $this->db->prepare( $sql )->execute( array($username, $crypt, $email, $ip, $time, $email_code, $firstName, $lastName) );

        mail( $email, 'Please activate your account', "Hello $firstName ,
        \r\nThank you for registering with us. 
        \r\n Username :  $username 
        \r\n Password :  $password 
        \r\n Please visit the link below so we can activate your account:\r\n\r\n
         http://example.com/Activate/$email/$email_code/
         \r\n\r\n--" . SITE_ROOT );

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();

        throw new \Exception( "Sorry, we were unable to create this account. Please try again." );
    }
    return true;
}
```

mail() is a built in PHP function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] );

Comment: IMO using mail is not the finest way to send mails if you already mentioned validation

Comment: 99% of what was written has nothing to do with the question.